# How to get the selected value from drop down in the same jsp

Tags: struts2

I have one drop down list in jsp.

```
 <s:select name="turboFilter.key" list="filterKeyList" listKey="key" listValue="key" />
```

Now i want the user selected value in another tag or in the jsp, say for ex, i wanted to print the user selected value in the same jsp, how to get it ? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With javascript for example.

Comment: With javascript we can get it its fine, but i need the drop down value in another tag say for ex , i need it in the <s:checkboxlist >
     <s:checkboxlist list="%{servPerCluster ['SAMPLEVALUE']}"  name="server.name" />    


Here SAMPLEVALUE should be replaced by the user selected drop down value.

Here servPerCluster is a map: private Map<String, List<String>> servPerCluster;

Comment: This makes no sense AT ALL. Struts tags are evaluated SERVER side. Once the page is rendered to the user, and he/she selects a value from the dropdown, you need to use some client-side technology to alter the value of the generated HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your replies,
I am able to fix the issue, through javascript and ajax